Convert timed events to a time series with observations Python
I have a list of events with a start and an end time. For example,

I want to accumulate these events into a time series, something like this:

The goal is to know how many concurring events are happening at any given time.
Ultimately, I would want to plot this time series as something like this:

I want to automate this processing in python.
I know my way around basic data-related Python.

Could you clarify what you're asking for?  Do you want someone to provide complete working sample code?  Or do you just need advice on parsing the inputs and formatting the outputs?  Or do you only need a sketch of how the algorithm might be designed?  Or...?

Hi @JDM-GBG, I could adapt a proposed algorithm to my problem. Also, if any suggested libraries/functions could be used, that would be nice.

This is a solution to your problem, although it only counts the number of events (it does not naturally gives the list of the concerned events):
First, to create the pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Event': [
        'Event 1', 'Event 2','Event 3', 'Event 4', 'Event 5',
        'Event 6', 'Event 7', 'Event 8', 'Event 9', 'Event 10'
    ],
    'Start time': [
        '26/09/2024 9:15', '26/09/2024 9:25', '26/09/2024 9:29', 
        '26/09/2024 9:35', '26/09/2024 9:55', '26/09/2024 10:02', 
        '26/09/2024 10:07', '26/09/2024 10:15', '26/09/2024 10:35', 
        '26/09/2024 10:45'
    ],
    'End time': [
        '26/09/2024 10:00', '26/09/2024 10:00', '26/09/2024 10:14', 
        '26/09/2024 10:25', '26/09/2024 10:40', '26/09/2024 10:52', 
        '26/09/2024 10:42', '26/09/2024 11:00', '26/09/2024 11:25', 
        '26/09/2024 11:30'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert the time columns to datetime
df['Start time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df['End time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

Then the actual solution, which uses a system of counters (positive for an event start, negative for an event end):
# create counter columns, +1 for the event start, -1 for the event end
df["start_counter"] = 1
df["end_counter"] = -1
# create a new dataframe with only two columns : time and counter
times = pd.concat(
    [
        df[["Start time", "start_counter"]].rename(
            columns={"Start time": "Date time", "start_counter": "counter"}
        ), 
        df[["End time", "end_counter"]].rename(
            columns={"End time": "Date time", "end_counter": "counter"}
        )
    ]
)
# sort values
times.sort_values(by="Date time", inplace=True)
# compute number of ongoing events
times["Concurring events"] = times["counter"].cumsum()

